# Nexus 5 Noise with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-5

With the phone and Bluetooth paired in my SUV there's a scratchy tapping noise every time I make or receive a call. Any idea how to get rid of this tapping noise? The phone is right up front with me in the open (not in my pocket) so I don't think its a distance issue.  I've had other older model Android phones pair without this noise.

Comment: This could be the noise that is generated by the Radio waves in your speaker/amplifyer. If you cannot give an example of that sound it is really hard to debug. I wanted to post that as a comment, but my reputation is to low for that...